# tensor product of two column stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, stochastic-matrices

Is the tensor product of two column/row stochastic matrix is again a column/row stochastic?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tensor product of two $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ is
$$A\otimes B = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} a_{11}B & \ldots& a_{1n}B\\
\vdots & \ldots & \vdots\\
a_{n1}B & \ldots & a_{nn} B
\end{array}\right).$$
So if $A,B$ are column stochastic, then so is $A\otimes B$. Just check the $j$-th column of the block matrix $A\otimes B$ and take inside the block matrix the $k$-th column of $B$:
$$a_{1j}[b_{1k}+\ldots+b_{nk}] + \ldots + a_{nj}[b_{1k}+\ldots+b_{nk}] = a_{1j}+\ldots+a_{nj} = 1.$$
Similar for the rows.